# Is Chance Gilbert Based On Real Life Historic Figures or Cult-Leaders?

Tags: character, longmire

In the TV series ***Longmire***, there is a reoccuring villainous character named **Chance Gilbert** (Peter Stormare); a verbally-whimsical, urban, & sociopathic (by TV standards) **cult-leader with idealisms** of an **American Survivalist**. He often uses his beliefs of liberty and freedom to enact violence and challange current American Law.

[image: Gilbert Cult]

My question is, **is Chance Gilbert based on any [American-related] historical figures (founding fathers, politicians, philosophers) and/or any iconic cult-leaders like Jim Jones or Charles Manson?**

I'm looking for anything conclusive from the Executive Producers, Writers, or Actors. I'm also open to answers pertaining to source material should this character or a very similar character exist there and/or has been talked about in interviews from the author.